# Express v4: How do I run route-specific middleware before param middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Long story short, I have a rather odd routing scenario where I need to invoke a middleware before the parameter middleware is invoked:

```
router.param('foo', function (req, res, next, param) {
  // Get the param value
  ...
  next()
})

router.route('/:foo')
  .all(function (req, res, next) {
    // I want to run this before the router.param middleware
    // but I don't want to run this on /:foo/bar
    ...
    next()
  })
  .get(function (req, res, next) {
    // Run this after the router.param middleware
    ...
    res.send('foo')
  })

router.route('/:foo/bar')
  .get(function (req, res, next) {
    // Run this after the router.param middleware
    ...
    res.send('bar')
  })
```

Now, I understand why the param middleware is typically run first, but is there a way around this?

I've tried to use `router.use` **without** a path like so:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // I want to run this before the router.param middleware
  // but I don't want to run this on /:foo/bar
  ...
  next()
})
```

...and call it before the router.param middleware but then it would be invoked for `/:foo/bar` as well.

Finally, if I use `router.use` **with** a path like so:

```
router.use('/:foo', function (req, res, next) {
  // I want to run this before the router.param middleware
  // but I don't want to run this on /:foo/bar
  ...
  next()
})
```

...the router.param middleware gets called first (as you would expect).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert at regular expressions, but you can use regular expressions to match routes. This would work for your specific use case, although there may be a better way of doing it.

```
router.use(/^\/[^\/]*$/, function(req, res, next) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordonias. One slight update to the regex would be ```/^\/[^\/]*\/?$/``` to account for a possible trailing slash in the URL. I'm still curious if there are other, like you said, 'better' (perhaps 'official' is a better term?) ways of doing this.